# MySQL fulltext search does not find existing record

Tags: mysql, search, match, full-text-search, match-against

I have found interesting issue within my MySQL fulltext search using **MATCH** function. Everything is fine except the records are incorrectly returned - only few of them.

Example:

> There is a record in "song" table with "name" = **22** (only two characters)

a) When i use this MySQL query (LIKE) I get the record listed.

```
SELECT * FROM `song` WHERE name like '%22%';
```

b) When I use this MySQL query (MATCH) I get NO record.

```
SELECT * FROM `song` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('*22*' IN BOOLEAN MODE );
```

I do not understand why the slower **LIKE** works like charm but the **MATCH** has the problem.

1. There is a FULLTEXT index set on "name" column
2. I tried to change **ft_min_word_len** variable to "2" but does not work.
3. I work with MySQL 8.0.30, InnoDB tables type

Can anybody explain me, why I can't find the existing record with fulltext function?

Tahnks!

Comment: You need to restart MySQL after changing [`innodb_ft_min_token_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) and then [rebuild your fulltext index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-rebuild-innodb-indexes).